# APK not installed error while installing apk from firebase auto update [Debug APK]

Tags: android, firebase, apk, auto-update

I have used firebase for auto-update. for that, I have uploaded debug apk on Firebase storage and got the link from that file. After in Firebase realtime database, I have updated the link and version. when I check in the app I am getting an update popup but after downloading that while I am trying to install it showing aPK not installed. Debug apk is not overwritten on the installed apk. If I installed that file after uninstalling the previous apk it is working.